# How to use expose in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, endpoint

In my dockerfile I defined:

```
EXPOSE 5050
```

Is there a way where I can give it an endpoint name as we can give in any REST frameworks, so that I can send a request to `localhost:5050/<ENDPOINT_NAME>`?

Comment: After exposing port 5050, you can run your docker images with port forward 
"docker run -d -p 5050:5050  image_name"
you can get your response using ip and port 5050.

Comment: @TayburRahaman I want access it as localhost:5050/getQuery .  So, where or how do we need to define "getQuery"?

Comment: You need some sort of HTTP reverse proxy; Nginx is a popular choice.  At a Docker level, there's no guarantee your service will actually speak HTTP (the standard MySQL, MongoDB, PostgreSQL, and Redis images all `EXPOSE` their normal ports).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a reverse proxy software. Here's an easy to use Nginx container that is very popular:

https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/letsencrypt/

after that, you just configure the proxy config to suit your needs. A basic idea of what one looks like is:

```
location /yourapp {
    return 301 $scheme://$host/yourapp/;
}
location ^~ /yourapp/ {

    include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
    set $upstream_app yourapp;
    set $upstream_port 5050;
    set $upstream_proto http;
    proxy_pass $upstream_proto://$upstream_app:$upstream_port;

}
```

Using the above example, then you'd be able to enter something like:

```
https://yourdomain.com/yourapp/getQuery
```

and it'll get redirected to where you want it over at the `5050` port.

Here's their entire list of current reverse proxy configs, to give you more ideas on how they work:

https://github.com/linuxserver/reverse-proxy-confs